# How to use the value in .h files, which are same name but different directory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, directory

How to get the value from .h(3D model) which are different 3D model but same name and different directory?

For Example:

`A1.h` (Banana model) is in `/FrameMarkers/Model/A1.h`

`A1.h` (Tiger model) is in `/FrameMarkers/Model1/A1.h`

But, I want to get values from the variables, which are A1NumVerts, A1Verts, A1Normal, A1TexCoords from both of them in order to use for my condition.
here is the code:

```
int Type=Animal;
 - (void) setup3dObjects
 {
     if(Type==Animal){
     [self add3DObjectWith:A1NumVerts ofVertices:A1Verts normals:A1Normals texcoords:A1TexCoords                        
                      with:NUM_R_OBJECT_INDEX ofIndices:RobjectIndices usingTextureIndex:0];                                     <<<<<<<<<<<< show Tiger
     }
     else
     {        
         [self add3DObjectWith:A1NumVerts ofVertices:A1Verts normals:A1Normals texcoords:A1TexCoords
                          with:NUM_R_OBJECT_INDEX ofIndices:RobjectIndices usingTextureIndex:0];                                    <<<<<<<<<<<< show Banana
     }
 }
```

How can I change the code that I underline in order to get the value from them?

Answer (score 0):

If you can rename the variables in those files manually so they're not the same, that's probably the best solution.

A second solution is to write 2 helper functions which return the 2 models, and which are in different implementation files. Something like this:

Banana.h:

```
void getBananaData (int* numVerts, Vertex* verts, Normal* normals, TexCoords* texCoords); // Where Vertex* and Normal* are whatever types A1Verts and A1Normals are
```

Banana.m:

```
#include "FrameMarkers/Model/A1.h"

void getBananaData (int* numVerts, Vertex* verts, Normal* normals, TexCoords* texCoords)
{
    // These will give you the data from the banana model
    // because we included the banana model's header and not the
    // tiger model's.
    *numVerts = A1NumVerts;
    *verts = A1Verts;
    *normals = A1Normals;
    *texCoords = A1TexCoords;
}
```

Then do the same thing but for the Tiger model:

Tiger.h

```
void getTigerData (int* numVerts, Vertex* verts, Normal* normals, TexCoords* texCoords);
```

and the Tiger.m

```
#include "FrameMarkers/Model1/A1.h"

void getTigerData (int*numVerts, Vertex* verts, Normal* normals, TexCoords* texCoords)
{
    // These will give you the data from the tiger model
    // because we included the tiger model's header, and not the banana model's
    *numVerts = A1NumVerts;
    *verts = A1Verts; 
    *normals = A1Normals;
    *texCoords = A1TexCoords;
}
```

Then in your method above, you'd have something like this:

```
 int numVerts = 0;
 Vertex verts;
 Normals normals;
 TexCoords texCoords;
 if(Type==Animal){
     getTigerData(&numVerts, &verts, &normals, &texCoords);
 }
 else
 {        
     getBananaData (&numVerts, &verts, &normals, &texCoords);
 }
 [self add3DObjectWith:numVerts ofVertices:verts normals:normals texcoords:A1TexCoords with:NUM_R_OBJECT_INDEX ofIndices:RobjectIndices usingTextureIndex:0];
```

A third solution would be to use a `#define` to rename the variables in one of the files at compile time. This is not my favorite solution because it can cause other problems. I can explain it, but you probably don't want to do it.

Comment: Thx u for your helping. But Is it possible to get the value from them if the names are same. I have a reason that why I can't rename because I must do like to for a lots of models. So I wouldn't like to change the code in .h file.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote above, you can make helper functions in different headers, and having the implementations in separate files which each include only one of the headers with variables of the same name.